# Subsrate Node Build error: cannot find macro `thread_local` in this scope

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

Whole error:

```rs
error: cannot find macro `thread_local` in this scope
    --> /home/hardeep/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/externalities/src/scope_limited.rs:22:1
     |
  22 | environmental::environmental!(ext: trait Externalities);
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: `thread_local` is in scope, but it is an attribute: `#[thread_local]`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::thread_local_impl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `environmental::environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0425]: cannot find value `GLOBAL` in this scope
    --> /home/hardeep/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/externalities/src/scope_limited.rs:22:1
     |
  22 | environmental::environmental!(ext: trait Externalities);
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::environmental` which comes from the expansion of the macro `environmental::environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

     Compiling hash-db v0.16.0
     Compiling hashbrown v0.12.3
  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
  error: could not compile `sp-externalities` (lib) due to 4 previous errors
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

rustups show:

```
hardeep@LAPTOP-M6QACF70:~/substrate/substrate-node-template$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/hardeep/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (directory override for '/home/hardeep/substrate/substrate-node-template')
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
```

I tried all the things like installing wasm32-unknown-unknown.I also tried updating cargo with cargo update, before used cargo clean and used cargo build --release. also tried to pull if there were problem with my subsrate current node. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Which version substrate are you working on ?